# what do need to fix for this answer check to work?

Tags: python, math

im a newbie trying to make a random math question generator and the numbers i give the system will output to the question area but when i give the right answer (e.x. 3 times 3 is 9) the system wont see the answer as right.[image]

iv tried about 15 different iterations of the code you see here and this is what closest to working

```
import random
from tkinter import *

na = random.randint(1, 3)
nb = random.randint(1, 3)
txtstring = ("what is", na,"*", nb,"?")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x320")
root.title(" Q&A ")
 
def Take_input():
    INPUT = inputtxt.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(INPUT)
    if(INPUT == na * nb):
        Output.insert(END, 'Correct')
    else:
        Output.insert(END, "Wrong answer")
     
l = Label(text = txtstring)
inputtxt = Text(root, height = 10,
                width = 25,
                bg = "light yellow")
 
Output = Text(root, height = 5,
              width = 25,
              bg = "light cyan")
 
Display = Button(root, height = 2,
                 width = 20,
                 text ="Show",
                 command = lambda:Take_input())
 
l.pack()
inputtxt.pack()
Display.pack()
Output.pack()
 
mainloop()
```

Comment: I haven't used tkinter but im guessing `INPUT` is a string not a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inputtxt.get` returns a string, but `na * nb` is an `int`. So in your example, you're comparing the string `"6"` against the integer `6`. You need to convert `INPUT` to an integer, otherwise the comparison against `na * nb` will always fail. E.g.,

```
if(int(INPUT) == na * nb):
```

You can improve this code further by handling non-numeric inputs appropriately, but this is the root of the problem.

Comment: thank you very much ill try this
edit: this was the solution